# Cannot install stellargraph

Tags: python, conda, stellargraph

I am trying to install [stellargraph](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/README.html#installation) package. I created a new conda environment with python 3.6 and tried to install it with `pip install stellargraph` but when I try to write `import stellargraph` in jupyter, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stellargraph'`.

I also tried it with PyCharm to create a new conda enironment with python 3.6 and then use its package manager to install stellargraph. It installs successfully but when I import it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/Univ/Computer/10th/Network/Project/pycharm/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stellargraph
  File "/home/hossein/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from stellargraph import (
  File "/home/hossein/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/data/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .loader import from_epgm
  File "/home/hossein/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/data/loader.py", line 23, in <module>
    from stellargraph.data.epgm import EPGM
  File "/home/hossein/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/data/epgm.py", line 24, in <module>
    import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [apparently a known packaging bug in the library](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/issues/2039); it inadvertently imports `chardet` but doesn't actually use it.

To work around this, install `chardet` by hand too: `pip install chardet`.

(It's likely that this is just an oversight caused by the fact that `chardet` did generally get installed with `requests` before they switched to `charset-normalizer`; `chardet` was used in some commented-out code in stellargraph.)

This has been fixed [in this (unrelated) commit](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/commit/ebe617fb2ab977d250c1f568dd25e4769d7e31af) that hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I just had an "aha" moment reading this answer. When writing code, you should always declare dependencies that you use directly, even if one of your dependencies also uses it. So if package A uses package B so that they are always installed together, then you should still add package B to your requirements.txt/pyproject.toml/whatever if you use it directly yourself.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Generally, you should only declare the dependencies you use yourself, not transitive dependencies (deps used by other deps). You could use a lockfile (generated e.g. with pip-compile) to lock down _all_ deps, but that's a different file than requirements.txt/pyproject.toml/.... However, _this_ answer is an outlier case, since the `stellargraph` library is mis-packaged.

Comment: "you should only declare the dependencies you use yourself: that's what i said. Specifically, that you should declare a dependency directly even if it happens to also be a transitive dependency. And yes,  my comment is a tangent from this answer, so maybe I shouldn't have posted. I just had what I thought was an amazing insight.